# parsing dynamic JSON Response

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    'AddUpdateResult': {
        "Patient": "24919"
    }
}
```

Here is a part of my response, The problem i am facing is the JSON response i am getting is dynamic and i need to parse it. In another scenario, i get something like this.

```
   {
        'EditUpdateResult': {
            "Patient": "24919"
        }
    }
```

When i try something like this, i get "`Cannot read property Patient from null`" and the reason is its expecting "`EditUpdateResult`".

```
json.AddUpdateResult.Patient
```

How can i access the key's dynamically. Like... `json.whatever.Patient`, so that it may `AddUpdateResult` or `EditUpdateResult`

Comment: Are you only dealing with two possible responses, or do you need a more general solution that can deal with any response that has a "patient" property?

Comment: That isn't JSON. Strings can't be quoted using `'` characters.

Comment: JSON properties are quoted with double quotes, not single. Where is the JSON in your code? Is it a string? did you parse it into a JS object? Questions without code are hard to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all of the responses only have one 'result'? If so try looping over it like this:

```
var patient;

for (var i in json) {
    patient = json[i].Patient;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to iterate over a JSON object without knowing the attribute names.

```
for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `hasOwnProperty` is useful if your object may have been prototyped. That probably isn't the case in this example (based on the supplied data), but good point nonetheless.